# How to create pre url subdomains using MAMP Pro

Tags: mamp

I am using MAMP to develop a site and I wanted to know if there is a way to create pre url subdomains from within the software itself. IE  http://subdomain.mywebsite.com

I want to stay away from all the complexity of messing with apache config if possible but if there is no other way than that's fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAMP do not provide the possibility to create hosts. But you can use [MAMP PRO](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/index.html) to create hosts with any name you want. You can also add aliases to host with any name you want.